# ihover is not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to work out ihover with bootstrap  but its not working. I searched for this problem and tried the solution provided but still its not working. The answer is not satisfactory.This is the code that I am trying to implement. I took it from [this link.](http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/index.html) I added css from [this link.](https://github.com/gudh/ihover/blob/gh-pages/src/ihover.css) Please tell me what am I missing?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="ih-item square effect7">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="img"><img src="homepage-pics/electrician.jpg"></div>
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Electrician</h3>
            <p>Need an electrician?<a href="#">click here</a></p>
          </div>
         </a>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The code looks ok. Have you properly referenced the iHover stylesheet?

Comment: yes sir. the problem is not in css. its the `<a>` element in `<p>` element which was creating problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the anchor in your `.info p` tag. if you remove the anchor from this `<p>`, it works.

```css
.ih-item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out
}
.ih-item,
.ih-item * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.ih-item a {
  color: #333
}
.ih-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none
}
.ih-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.ih-item.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.ih-item.circle .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.ih-item.circle .img:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out
}
.ih-item.circle .img img {
  border-radius: 50%
}
.ih-item.circle .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden
}
.ih-item.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 316px;
  height: 216px;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
.ih-item.square .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 .img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 .info {
  background: #333;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.35s ease 0.2s
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 .info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 .info p {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 a:hover .img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7 a:hover .info {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.left_to_right .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.left_to_right a:hover .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.right_to_left .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.right_to_left a:hover .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.top_to_bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.top_to_bottom a:hover .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.bottom_to_top .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%)
}
.ih-item.circle.effect7.bottom_to_top a:hover .info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0)
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 {
  overflow: hidden
}
.ih-item.square.effect7.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72;
  background: rgba(26, 74, 114, 0.6)
}
.ih-item.square.effect7.colored .info h3 {
  background: rgba(12, 34, 52, 0.6)
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 .img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1)
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 .info {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 .info h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #111;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(4);
  -moz-transform: scale(4);
  -ms-transform: scale(4);
  -o-transform: scale(4);
  transform: scale(4);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s 0.1s ease-in-out
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 .info p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  -o-transform: scale(5);
  transform: scale(5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.35s 0.3s linear
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 a:hover .img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 a:hover .info {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
.ih-item.square.effect7 a:hover .info h3,
.ih-item.square.effect7 a:hover .info p {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="ih-item square colored effect7">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/images/assets/rect/4.jpg" alt="img">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Electrician</h3>
            <p>Need an electrician?<!--<a href="#">click here</a>-->
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: sir could you please tell me why was that `<a>` element creating problem?